# Specifying host in rewrite rule causes URL to change

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have the rewrite rule

```
RewriteRule (/m)?/cia16(.*) $1/cia$2?CIA=16 [QSA]
```

This works fine, but the problem is that it is running as the environment of multiple hosts, but it only tries to redirect to the main host.  For example, this is in the configuration for `dev.example.com`, but the rewrite redirects to *dev* even if you are on `explosion-pills.dev.example.com` (which has the same config).

I can fix that with:

```
RewriteRule (/m)?/cia16(.*) http://${HTTP_HOST}$1/cia$2?CIA=16 [QSA]
```

...however, this causes the URL to change in the address bar which is undesirable.  Using the `[L]` flag does nothing either.

How should I specify the rewrite rule to use the current host without changing the request URL?

Comment: Do you have another rule after the one in your question that is causing the redirecting to dev?

Comment: Not that I know of, but I don't have much control over the main configuration file

Comment: Someone else had a similar issue and seemingly fixed it using the `Passthrough` flag. Worth a try? http://www.sitepoint.com/forums/showthread.php?617120-Replicating-internal-redirect-behaviour-for-redirecting-to-external-site-in-htaccess

Comment: There is no `R` flag in the first rule. What do you mean with redirect to the main host? What exactly happens when you try some URL?

Answer (score 1):

One way to solve is to enable `mod_proxy` in your Apache config. Once that is done use `P` (proxy) flag in Rewrite like this:

```
RewriteRule (/m/)?cia16(.*) http://%{HTTP_HOST}$1/cia$2?CIA=16 [QSA,L,P]
```

Comment: Yes sorry `${HTTP_HOST}` was a typo but are you sure mod_proxy is enabled and working in you Apache config.

Comment: Also pls let me know what URI did you use to test this?

Comment: Just `/cia16/`.  `mod_proxy` is not enabled; I don't think NOC is going to enable it either.

Comment: Oh ok my answer started with `One way to solve is to enable mod_proxy in your Apache config` so I thought may be you got it enabled somehow :) Can you try this rule instead: `RewriteRule (/m/)?cia16(.*) http://%{HTTP_HOST}$1/cia$2?CIA=16 [QSA,L,R]`

Comment: Sorry I assumed that it was before, but after talking to them they said "definitely not;" I'll give this a try, thanks